# Woocommerce rearrange checkout fields

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have rearranged the order fields on the Woocommerce checkout page with this function:

```
    //Reorder checkout
    add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields', 'reorder_woo_fields' ); 
    function reorder_woo_fields( $fields ) {
    $fields2['billing']['billing_first_name'] = $fields['billing']  ['billing_first_name'];
    $fields2['billing']['billing_last_name']  = $fields['billing']['billing_last_name'];
    $fields2['billing']['billing_company'] =  $fields['billing']['billing_company'];
    $fields2['billing']['billing_address_1']  = $fields['billing']['billing_address_1'];
    $fields2['billing']['billing_city']       = $fields['billing']['billing_city'];
    $fields2['billing']['billing_postcode']   = $fields['billing']['billing_postcode'];
    $fields2['billing']['billing_country']    = $fields['billing']['billing_country'];
    $fields2['billing']['billing_email']      = $fields['billing']['billing_email'];
    $fields2['billing']['billing_phone']      = $fields['billing']['billing_phone'];

    $fields2['shipping']['shipping_first_name'] = $fields['shipping']['shipping_first_name'];
    $fields2['shipping']['shipping_last_name'] = $fields['shipping']['shipping_last_name'];
    $fields2['shipping']['shipping_company'] =  $fields['shipping']['shipping_company'];
    $fields2['shipping']['shipping_address_1'] = $fields['shipping']['shipping_address_1'];
    $fields2['shipping']['shipping_city'] = $fields['shipping']['shipping_city'];
    $fields2['shipping']['shipping_postcode'] = $fields['shipping']['shipping_postcode'];
    $fields2['shipping']['shipping_country'] = $fields['shipping']['shipping_country'];

    // Add full width Classes and Clears to Adjustments    
    $fields2['billing']['billing_first_name'] = array(
        'label' => __('First Name', 'woocommerce'),
    'class'     => array('form-row-wide'),
    'clear'     => true,
    'required' => true
     );
     $fields2['billing']['billing_last_name'] = array(
    'label' => __('Last Name', 'woocommerce'),
    'class'     => array('form-row-wide'),
    'clear'     => true,
        'required' => true
     );
     $fields2['shipping']['shipping_first_name'] = array(
        'label' => __('First Name', 'woocommerce'),
    'class'     => array('form-row-wide'),
    'clear'     => true,
    'required' => true
     );
     $fields2['shipping']['shipping_last_name'] = array(
    'label' => __('Last Name', 'woocommerce'),
    'class'     => array('form-row-wide'),
    'clear'     => true,
        'required' => true
     );
     return $fields2;
     }
```

and this works, but when enabling debug mode I am getting an error on the chekcout page:
Notice: Undefined index: order in /html/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates/checkout/form-shipping.php on line 58

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /html/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates/checkout/form-shipping.php on line 58

Can aynone make sense of this?

Comment: First thing I see is you have an extra space between ['billing'] and ['billing_first_name']. This could be the cause of your problem

Answer (score 5):

You can try below code for reorder the checkout page fields. You can chnage the order of fields in the array.

```
// for billing fields

add_filter("woocommerce_checkout_fields", "new_order_fields");

function new_order_fields($fields) {

    $order = array(
        "billing_company", 
        "billing_first_name", 
        "billing_last_name", 
        "billing_address_1", 
        "billing_address_2", 
        "billing_postcode", 
        "billing_country", 
        "billing_email", 
        "billing_phone"
    );
    foreach( $order as $field ) {
        $ordered_fields[$field] = $fields["billing"][$field];
    }

    $fields["billing"] = $ordered_fields;
    return $fields;    
}

// for shipping fields
add_filter("woocommerce_checkout_fields", "new_shiping_order_fields");

function new_shiping_order_fields($fields) {

    $order = array(   
        "shipping_city", 
        "shipping_postcode", 
        "shipping_country",    
        "shipping_first_name", 
        "shipping_last_name", 
        "shipping_company", 
        "shipping_address_1", 
        "shipping_address_2"

    );
    foreach( $order as $field ) {
        $ordered_fields[$field] = $fields["shipping"][$field];
    }

    $fields["shipping"] = $ordered_fields;
    return $fields;
}
```

Comment: This will only rearrange the fields, but I also need to remove the order notes field AND add full width to certain fields (see in my code above)...

Answer (score 0):

You can find a complete guide about that in [the WooCommerce docs](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/tutorial-customising-checkout-fields-using-actions-and-filters/).

You are defining a new array `$fields2` and this array doesn't have all the fields required in `woocommerce_checkout_fields`. You only need to override `$fields["billing"]` and `$fields["shipping"]` just like [@pallavi showed you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39107445/woocommerce-rearrange-checkout-fields#39116661).

To remove a field (ex. order_comments) you can put this line in your function

```
unset($fields['order']['order_comments']);
```